# 3D equivalent to Visio

Tags: 3d, visualization

Anyone recommend a tool. Commercial or freeware that allows things to be dropped into 3D Space then linked in various ways. This structure can be viewed rotated, flown through etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an addon for Visio, called [3D Visioner](http://samposoftware.com/3dvisioner). Its commercial, and I have not used it myself, but there is a free trial so might be worth a shot.

[alt text http://samposoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/screen13.png](http://samposoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/screen13.png)

Comment: Thanks. This might be perfect as I know Visio well. Will Check it out.

Comment: As I could not vote when I first posted this question I thought I should return and do the right thing as this answer was perfect for me

Comment: Thanks for the +1. You can also mark an answer as the accepted one, to indicate that it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) has both free and pay-for versions.